# MVC DataReader connection related issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two models with a navigation property in one to the other. Model looks like this:
I am calling the two models in the same view. SuiteCategoryModels as the default and SuitesModels as a partial view.

```
public class SuiteCategoryModels
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SuiteCatID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string CatName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Category Description")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string CatDesc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SuitesModels> SuitesModels { get; set; }
}
```

and the second model like this:

```
      public class SuitesModels
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SuiteID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Suite Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string SuiteName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 6 characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string SuiteDesc { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    [Display(Name = "Picture")]
    public string SuitePix { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Rate")]
    public int SuiteRate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Persons Per Suite")]
    public int PersonPerSuite { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public bool SuiteStatus { get; set; }

    public int SuiteCatID { get; set; }

    public virtual SuiteCategoryModels SuiteCategory { get; set; }
}
```

I created a controller action to view like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var m = db.SuiteCategoryModels.ToList();
        //ViewBag.BB = 
        //Dispose(false);
        return View(m);
    }
```

and the other like this:

```
 public ActionResult SuitesIndex(int id = 0)
    {
        var mm = db.Suites.Select(r => r.SuiteCategory)
                  .Where(r => r.SuiteCatID == id);
        //SuitesModels suitesmodels = db.Suites.Find(id);
        if (mm == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("SuitesIndex", mm.ToList());
    }
```

But I have an error page stating: `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`.

1. What are the reasons of this error?
2. What do I do to correct this?

Comment: Does db refer to the same instance in both cases, such as a class member? If not, it should.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927990/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma

Comment: in which line of code you get this error?

Comment: Where are you disposing of your context? From the snippets you are providing it doesn't look like you are, which is not a good idea. Any time you are dealing with connections to a database you really should be closing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` to your connection string.